# How do I convert the following String Date into Java Data format in Java?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

How do i convert the following String Date into Data format in Java?

```
"10/01/2012  06:45:23:245946"
```

I am using the following code

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy  hh24:mm:ss:SSS");
java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("10/01/2012  06:45:23:245946");
```

And i am getting the following error

```
    java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "10/01/2012  06:45:23:245946"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `hh24` in [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), You should be using `HH`

Answer (score 5):

Your pattern is wrong. Try:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss:SSS"
```

There is no `hh24` in date matching pattern.

The pattern for hour is as follows:

```
H  Hour in day (0-23)  Number  0  
k  Hour in day (1-24)  Number  24
```

See the whole date pattern on [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) javadoc.

Comment: hh is 12 hour based, he doesn't have am/pm so it will not work

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there.

Get rid of the 24 after hh and change it to HH, that should make it work.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss:SSS");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse("10/02/2012  06:45:23:245946");
System.out.println(parsedDate);
```

This will give you an error in time but parse the date successfull, as will all of our answers.
This is fixed by trimming the milliseconds down to 3 digits from `245946` to `245`

If you do however want to use 6 digits I would suggest looking into the JodaTime API for more advanced datehandling as JodaTime handles microseconds. But as for `java.util.Date`, you're out of luck I'm afraid.

Read this bugreport why:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4148168

EDIT: Thanks Jesper for pointing out my bad wording

Comment: Thanks for your  Answer. It is working. But the result date is wrong. It is Mon Oct 01 06:49:28 IST 201 (for 10/01/2012  06:45:23:245946).

Comment: It's cause SSS only takes 3 milliseconds, and not 6. This is something that has been around since 1.1.6 of Java. Read this Bugreport http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4148168

Comment: "6 digit milliseconds"? A millisecond is 1/1000th of a second. By definition it can have at most 3 digits. If we are talking about fractions of a second with 6 digits, it's microseconds (1/1000000th of a second), not milliseconds.

Comment: Absolutely, good point. JodaTime handles this gracefully but I should rephrase my answer. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `24` in your date format is an invalid format specifier.  Remove it.  `HH` is the equivalent of hours on a 24-hour scale.

```
dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss:SSS");
```