# String Date to java TimeStamp conversion

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp

I am trying to convert String to java Timestamp. I am using the following code

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss:SSS");
Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(value);
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());            
return timestamp;
```

My input is Input                    ::"10/01/2012  06:45:23:245946"

But i am getting Wrong Output   :: 2012-10-01 06:49:28.946

What is Wrong in this code??

Comment: Geeez .. how many times do you plan to post the same question?!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert the following String Date into Java Data format in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599865/how-do-i-convert-the-following-string-date-into-java-data-format-in-java)

Comment: @Java_Dinesh - your question was already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13599926/680925). Your really large input values for milliseconds is being converted into minutes, you need to restrict it down to three digits.

Comment: You have the answer in your same previous question.

Comment: Hi all i am really sorry for the unwanted post. But the value 245946 is actully a micro seconds.How do i handle micro seconds in SimpledateFormat. Note: 1.I need the exact value as output 2. I get the input using the following oracle Query (select to_char(systimestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual;). Thank you

Comment: Hi any one ans me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
10/01/2012 06:45:23:245946
```

Here you have passed 245946 milliseconds, which is actually converted into seconds and minutes and it become `2012-10-01 06:49:28.946`.

```
245946 milliseconds = 245 seconds and 946 milliseconds 
245 seconds 946 milliseconds = 4 minutes, 5 seconds and 946 milliseconds

so 06:45:23+ 4 minutes 5 seconds and 946 milliseconds = 
06 hour 49 minutes 28 seconds 946 miliseconds
```

Comment: Hi you are right. But 245946 is micro seconds. how do i mention the microseconds in SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy  HH:mm:ss:SSS");

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132247/custom-date-format-cannot-be-parsed-java)

Answer (score 0):

It's correct, all those extra milliseconds are just represented as full minutes and seconds when you print it back out.  Your input includes 245946 milliseconds, which is 4 minutes, 5 seconds, and 946 milliseconds.  So your output shows as 4 minutes and 5 seconds later with 946 trailing millis.

Comment: Hi you are right. But 245946 is micro seconds. how do i mention the microseconds in SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss:SSS");

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Parse given Date

Step2: Use the following constructor to get absolute timestamp

```
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp((year-1900), (month-1), date, hour, min, sec,nano);
```